# Java Threads synchronization unexpected output

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I am studying for the OCPJP exam and having a hard time understanding threads. In particular, I have this program out lined below. When I run this program I get the following output and it is confusing me.

```
Inside push method...
Inside push method now sleeping...
Exit from main()
Inside push method stopped sleeping...
Exiting push method...
Pushed: true
Popped: 2008
Inside push method...
Inside push method now sleeping...
Inside push method stopped sleeping...
Exiting push method...
Pushed: true
Inside push method...
Inside push method now sleeping...
Inside push method stopped sleeping...
Exiting push method...
Pushed: true
Popped: 2008
Inside push method...
Inside push method now sleeping...
Popped: 2008
```

What is getting me is the last line of the output. The api says the thread does not lose ownership of any monitors/lock when sleep is called. How is it that the following:

```
Inside push method now sleeping...
Popped: 2008
```

can occur since the moment we enter the synchronized  method push(), push() has the monitor/lock, why are we able execute the pop() method while the push() is sleeping? I need assistance, may someone please give an easy to understand explanation?

```
class StackImpl {                   //(1)


private Object[] stackArray;
private int topOfStack;

public StackImpl(int capacity){
    stackArray = new Object[capacity];
    topOfStack = -1;
}

//  public boolean push(Object element){                                    //(2a) non-synchronized
public synchronized boolean push(Object element){                   //(2b) synchronized
    if(isFull()) return false;
    System.out.println("Inside push method...");
    ++topOfStack;
    try{
        System.out.println("Inside push method now sleeping...");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println("Inside push method stopped sleeping...");} catch(Exception e){}                 //(3) Sleep a little
    stackArray[topOfStack] = element;
    System.out.println("Exiting push method...");
    return true;

}


//public Object pop(){                                              //(4a) non-synchronized
public synchronized Object pop(){                                   //(4b) synchronized
    if(isEmpty()) return null;
    Object obj = stackArray[topOfStack];
    stackArray[topOfStack] = null;
    try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception e){}                        //(5) Sleep a little
    topOfStack--;
    return obj;

}

public boolean isEmpty(){return topOfStack < 0;}
public boolean isFull(){return topOfStack >= stackArray.length - 1;}


}


public class Mutex{
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    final  StackImpl stack = new StackImpl(20);                     //(6) Shared by the threads

    (new Thread("Pusher"){                                          //(7) Thread no. 1  
        public void run(){
            for(;;){
                System.out.println("Pushed: " + stack.push(2008));
            }
        }
    }).start();

    // make sure Thread no.1 goes first
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    (new Thread("Popper"){                                          //(8) Thread no.2
        public void run(){
            for(;;){
                System.out.println("Popped: " + stack.pop());
            }
        }
    }).start();


    System.out.println("Exit from main()");



}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is consistent, but it doesn't directly correspond with operations on the stack (the separate calls to `println` and `pop`/`push` are not atomic).  In Java, it is correct that you don't release the lock on the monitor in a `Thread.sleep(n)` (however it isn't true for `Object.wait()`).

To see the actual order, you can modify what is put onto the stack...

```
final  StackImpl stack = new StackImpl(20);                     //(6) Shared by the threads


(new Thread("Pusher"){                                          //(7) Thread no. 1

    public void run(){

    int i = 0;

        for(;;){
            System.out.println("Pushed: " + stack.push(i++));
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Now you should be able to see which push corresponds with which pop.

Comment: Thank you Jason, I appreciate the help, I will give your solution a shot and see if I can understand it any better. I will come back and tell you if I do or don't.

Comment: The main point is that the call to `println` happens after a call to `push` or `pop`, but you can't say anything about the order between concurrent calls to `println` since you're only synchronizing within those two calls.